# Android webview calls browser activity

Tags: android, android-webview, webviewclient

I'm using webview in android 
and when I call loadURL it does a call to the browser activity

I need to show the webcontent inside my own activity as I have other stuff to be viewed in it
buttons, text, ,.. etc

Answer (score 0):

Use the `WebView.setWebViewClient(WebViewClient)` method ( http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) and override the `shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView, String)` method like this:

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {                                      

    @Override                                                                       
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {             
        if ( url.equals( "http://www.example.com" ) ) {                                      
            // Do something
            return true;                                                            
        }                                                                           

        // If we couldn't match the URL, the following line
        // lets the webview use default behaviour (i.e. open browser)
        return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);                           
    }                                                                               

});
```